# Problems in creating output file of my query result

Tags: php, mysql

Following is my sql query which worked fine when i ran it from phpmyadmin but when i ran the same query through PHP then the query  didnot worked and gave me following error. Kindly let me know how can I run this query from my php file so it will create the output file in the specified folder. Thanks,

**QUERY**

```
SELECT * FROM lahore_student INTO OUTFILE 'b://uploaded//data.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '".'"'."'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

`Output: It creates file to my b drive in FOLDER named as Uploaded`

**ERROR**:
File 'b:uploadeddata.csv' already exists

`NOTE: The uploaded folder was empty`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks you are trying to run this on a windows system, which requires special treatment of directory separators.

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM lahore_student INTO OUTFILE 'b:\\uploaded\\data.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '".'"'."'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Or:

```
SELECT * FROM lahore_student INTO OUTFILE 'b:/uploaded/data.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '".'"'."'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Also note that this will not overwrite an existing file (which is the error you are getting).  So you need to make sure that any file with that name is deleted first.

See the `The “\” path name separator character` section on this page in the MYSQL docs:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/limits-windows.html

Comment: Thanks mike, The files are creating even with php script but not in specified folder they are being created in my c drive in mysql folder. Any idea how can i enforece my path so output file will be created on my given path via php script.

Comment: @softgenic You need to use windows-style paths like I have shown in my answer.  The problem you are currently getting is you are using linux directory separators which windows doesn't recognize, so it just removes than and write s a file called `b:uploadeddata.csv` into the default mysql directory.

Comment: I used windows style paths , still no luck, files are getting saved in mysql folder... amazed why, where on the other hand i am dumping `csv` file with `local infile` successfully to my database and file path formatting is same for my query mentioned above :( .

Comment: @softgenic You might actually need to double the backslashes `b:\\uploaded\\data.csv` since the MYSQL uses `\` as an escape sequence.  Familiar with working with MySQL in a Windows environment myself.

Comment: @softgenic See my updated answer.  I found reference within MySQL docs on how to properly specify the file path.